# In TypeScript, how to generally check the instanceof of an object variable?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, properties, instanceof

I want to check if the *obj* object variable has all the properties of the Person interface.

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const jsonObj = `{
  name: "John Doe",
  age: 30,
}`;

const obj: Person = JSON.parse(jsonObj);

const isPerson = obj instanceof Person; // Person is not defined

console.log(isPerson); // true
```

When I execute this code, it yield `Person in not defined`!

I would expect the code to log true as the obj is an instance of Person.

```
  -----
```

**Answer Update: Alternative Working Solution Using zod Library**

TypeScript works only in compile-time, but instanceof is a runtime thing. You can't use on a type, because types doesn't exist in javascript.

You can use a validator library like [zod](https://zod.dev/). Then, you can infer the ("TypeScript") type of the object and validate it with [zod](https://zod.dev/).

Per example,

```
import { z } from 'zod';

export const ItemSchema = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
  description: z.string(),
  productServiceId: z.number().optional(),
});

export type Item = z.infer<typeof ItemSchema>;

const validateItems = (items: Item[]) => {
    const ItemSchemaArray = z.array(ItemSchema);
    // This line below will throw an error if the validation failed
    ItemSchemaArray.parse(items);
};
```

Konrad referenced this library in the comments below.

Thank you, @Konrad!

Comment: TypeScript works only in compile-time, but `instanceof` is a runtime thing. You can't use on a type, because types doesn't exist in javascript. You can use a validator like [zod](https://zod.dev)

Comment: [See what your code is compiled to](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3EcnA1SQK5kBG0LAL4ECCHLWRZeAK2roo2XAF5kAKQDKAeQByAOgAOcBRAAUAcjykK1AESqsAC1wARLBBsAaNh2oBmAAyCZgCULKLiYMjAGPKKyCpS0lEgtHAgSFgwaJg4YWIpWAA2ELqFWAwm0bE4ocgA9HXIdFwQQA)

Comment: Are you ***sure*** you want to use `instanceof` or is that [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: I understand.

The reading of code writing in TypeScript code is quite different then compile TypeScript code.

I will check the zod  library.

Comment: Can you provide the solution using Zod?

I just checked their documentation page.

It is quite overwhelming for me.

Comment: @Konrad, I have updated my answer with a working solution based on the library, zod, you have proposed.

- Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`interface`s are a static TypeScript feature. `instanceof` is a dynamic ECMAScript operator. `interface`s do not exist at runtime, and ECMAScript does not know anything about TypeScript types.

Therefore, you cannot test at runtime whether an object conforms to an `interface`.

You can use a validator library like [zod](https://zod.dev/). Then, you can infer the ("TypeScript") type of the object and validate it with [zod](https://zod.dev/).

Per example,

```
import { z } from 'zod';

export const ItemSchema = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
  description: z.string(),
  productServiceId: z.number().optional(),
});

export type Item = z.infer<typeof ItemSchema>;

const validateItems = (items: Item[]) => {
    const ItemSchemaArray = z.array(ItemSchema);
    // This line below will throw an error if the validation failed
    ItemSchemaArray.parse(items);
};
```

Konrad referenced this library in the comments above.

Thank you, @Konrad!

Comment: I understand that reading TypeScript code is different from reading compiled TypeScript code.

However, I think it would be great to have such an implementation of "instanceof" under the hood where the compiled TypeScript checks the existence of each key for the object.

Comment: Your proposal violates [TypeScript Design Goals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#goals) #3 and #9, and [Non-Goals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) #5 and #6.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a type guard function that checks if the object adheres to the types set out in the interface. So:
`function isPerson(obj: any): obj is Person { return obj && typeof obj.name === 'string' && typeof obj.age === 'number'; }`
will return true or false if either of the parameters are not the types specified.
You will then change your console log to `console.log(isPerson(obj));`

Comment: This solution, contrary to be general, only applies to an object that implements / is a Person. I wanted a general solution as my interfaces are way more complex; my interfaces as many key-value pairs.

Comment: Apologies for the misread. But agree that it would be nice to have a under the hood implementation of instanceof in TS. Unfortunately, there is no general way to check from what I can see.